# Not able to retain the spinner data in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have two buttons in activity and a Frame layout (id is fragment) in xml . And two fragment fr_first and and fr_second .

**When user click on first button**

> ```
> fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
> fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fr_first);
> fragmentTransaction.commit();
> ```

**When user click on second button**

> ```
> fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
> fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fr_second);
> fragmentTransaction.commit();
> ```

Now the issue is i have a spinner in Second Fragment and i hit a service to bind that spinner . **When ever user press second button every time service is hit and data is bind** . I also done some googling for addToBackstack(null) and some stuff but do not get any appropriate solution .Thanks in advance